# How do I set the name a child in Firebase to user input from a text field?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's how I want my data tree to look in Firebase:

users:

--Travis:

------travisData:

--Stephanie:

------stephanieData:

My problem is that I can't seem to name a child using user input from a textfield.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
ref = Database.database().reference()

let username = String(emailTextField.text!)

//ref.child("users").setValue(["username": username])

ref.child("users").setValue(["\(username)": calendar])
```

The commented out line creates a child named "username" with the textfield.text as its content. But how can I create a child whose name is the textfield.text, with other data as its content? I've tried multiple combinations of using .child and .setValue, but everything keeps throwing me an error when I try to use the username variable instead of a plain string.

Here's the error I get:
[image]

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The error message just says "Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException". When I right clicked on the red indicator, there were options "Reveal in Project Navigator" and "Reveal in Symbol Navigator" but not the option you said. I clicked on both of those and neither were helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that Firebase doesn't accept the "." symbol in their user names. You would get the same problem even if you typed a string of letters with a "." such as "adfojnajsdnfjs.fjknasd" instead of "username".

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
ref.child("users").child(username).setValue(calendar)
```

Although that depends on the value of `calendar`.

At the very least this should work:

```
ref.child("users").child(username).setValue(true)
```

And give you the following JSON:

```
"users": {
  "Travis": true
}
```

To write a more complex structure, you can for example do:

```
ref.child("users").child(username).child("name").setValue(username)
```

Which results in:

```
"users": {
  "Travis": {
    name: "Travis"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, I still get the same error, even when I just setValue(true). For some reason it doesn't like when I use the username variable which takes user input. I added a picture of the error.

Answer (score 0):

As your require, I think this code will help you

```
ref.child("users").child("\(inputUsername)").updateChildValues(["travidDataKey": userData])
```

And
[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb3Pc.png)

```
users:
       Travid2:
                travidDataKey:"Travid Data"
```