# Set firebase child name from text input

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

This is input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" maxlength="10" required placeholder="Enter Username">
```

And this is Javascript:

```
contactsRef.child("users/" + auth.uid + "/moath")
.set({ a1: $('#name').val(),})
```

This is what I get
[image: hello]

In JavaScript i have /moath I don't want it.

**But I want to set child name from input**

I have tried this:

```
contactsRef.child("users/" + auth.uid + "/('#name')")
.set({ a1: $('#name').val(), })
```

I've looked at this too but it wasn't helpful [How do I set the name a child in Firebase to user input from a text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50184560/how-do-i-set-the-name-a-child-in-firebase-to-user-input-from-a-text-field)

**Finally this is I want**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you need to do:

```
contactsRef.child("users/" + auth.uid + "/" + $('#name').val())
.set({ a1: $('#name').val()});
```